# Budget is not working when is added in an Array

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have Position and the Budget interface, when I add new position and budget from the dialog all interface of position is added but budget is shown 0 when i reload the page the budget it is working everything good.
I add a position and the position is added and is shown but the planned budget is 0 when I reload the page then everything it is OK, how can this happen what do you suggest me to do that automatically shown the budget to, not when the page is reload.

Here you have the code, 
This is the method to show the positions

```
  getPosition() {
return this.positions.sort((function (a, b) {
  if (a.name > b.name) {
    return 1;
  }})).filter(position => this.subproject.positionIds.includes(position.id)).toArray();
}
```

This is the template

```
 <tr *ngFor="let position of getPosition()">
<td>{{position.name}}</td>
                          <td>{{costTypes[position.costType]}}</td>
                          <td>{{getActualBudget(position).planned | number}}</td>
                          <td>{{currencies[position.currency]}}</td>
                          <td>{{states[position.state]}}</td>
```

Here is the interface of Position

```
export interface Position {
  id: string;
     subProjectId: string;
  name: string;
 currency: string;
 state: string;
 costType: string;
 budgetIds: string[];
 }
```

Here is the interface of Budget

```
 export interface Budget {
 id: string;
 positionId: string;
 created: Date;
 planned: number;
 blocked: number;
 used: number;
 free: number;
 transferred: number;
 transferredToId: string;
 commentUsed: string;
 commentFree: string;
```

}

Here is the actual budget

```
getActualBudget(position: Position): Budget {
return this.budgets.get(position.budgetIds[0], emptyBudget());
}
```

Here is the template of dialog.

```
 <app-input-field orientation="top" labelWidth="85px;" label="Planned 
  Budget *">
      <input type="number" min="1"  [(ngModel)]="newBudget.planned" 
      required style="width: 100%;">
     </app-input-field>
```

Here is the Utils for Budget

```
export function emptyBudget(): Budget {
return {
id: '',
positionId: '',
created: new Date(0),
planned: 0,
blocked: 0,
used: 0,
free: 0,
transferred: 0,
transferredToId: '',
commentUsed: '',
commentFree: ''
};
}
```

Here are the effects.

```
upsertBudgetEffect$ = this.actions$.ofType(UpsertBudgetAction.Type).pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.store),
    mergeMap(([action, state]: [UpsertBudgetAction, ApplicationState]) => {
      const url = environment.backend + '/api/planning/budgets';
      return this.httpClient.put<Budget>(url, action.payload).pipe(
        mergeMap(response => {
          const actions: Action[] = [new UpsertBudgetInternalAction(response)];
          const position = state.budcon.positions.get(response.positionId);

          if (position.budgetIds.includes(response.id)) {
            position.budgetIds.push(response.id);
            actions.push(new UpsertPositionInternalAction(position));
          }

          return actions;
        }),
        catchError(noOpHandler)
      );
    })
  );
```

Comment: Can you create a sample with stackblitz.com?

Comment: I have so many folders and code i think will not work because I have this connected with database.

Comment: well, you don't need al the folder to create a minimal prototype to detect you problem

Comment: I never used before stackblitz I don't know how it works, I know that will be better for you to show in stackblitz but I really don't know how to put my code there.

Comment: you can simply create a new angular project there, add your code to the app.component.html and app.component.ts and try to add just the minimal amount of code that will recreate the behavior of this particular component

Comment: @BorisLobanov Can I make after I close the dialog somehow to refresh the interface of budget ?

Comment: @Abedin are there any errors shown in your browser console?  Or this is purely a logical trouble?  Regarding stackblitz..  you could just go find a "starter" project, and port the parts of your work over to it.  During that time, you may even resolve your own issue as you work through it.

Comment: @AdamCox I used console.log and no problem was there everything is saved in the store but it appears in template like 0 and the logic of budgets don't work, when I change the page or refresh than everything is fine works as expected.
When I add new position with budget the created date is a number and when is reloaded it takes the created date and works fine.

Comment: @Abedin by "console" I am referring to chrome dev tools (F12).  What browser are you using?  I want to know if there are any errors being reported in the chrome dev tools.

Comment: I have the chrome dev tools, I am using google chrome and there is no error or something like this but in the dev tools at the created that is a date when I add a position with budget that created is a number and when I refresh takes the right date and than it works.

Comment: @Abedin..  here is a stackblitz I started with a service to help mock your data.  Go fork that, and sandbox your issue there.  Then post your new fork here.  Thanks!  https://stackblitz.com/edit/adamcox-jnjfvq?file=main.ts

Comment: @AdamCox thanks man I will write my code and than I will post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the Effects at the condifiton If you have an fail.
Change from 
 `if (position.budgetIds.includes(response.id))`

to

```
if (!position.budgetIds.includes(response.id))
```

Comment: Thanks dude it is working I didnt notice this little failure.